# MongoDB Change Stream for Azure CosmosDB MongoDB API

Tags: mongodb, azure-cosmosdb-mongoapi, changestream

I have to use MongoDB Change Stream. The MongoDB is setup using CosmosDB MongoDB API. Wire compatibility is supported.

Somehow I cannot setup a watch. Here is the code I am using:

```
string connectionstring="my connection string";
var mongoClient = new MongoClient(connectionstring);
var database = mongoClient.GetDatabase("Events");
var collection = database.GetCollection<BsonDocument>("ACollection");

var options = new ChangeStreamOptions() { FullDocument = ChangeStreamFullDocumentOption.UpdateLookup };

var pipeline = new EmptyPipelineDefinition<ChangeStreamDocument<BsonDocument>>().Match("{ operationType: 'insert' }");

var cursor = collection.Watch(pipeline, options).ToEnumerable();
```

This last last throws an exception

```
Unhandled exception. MongoDB.Driver.MongoCommandException: Command aggregate failed: Change stream must be followed by a match and then a project stage.
...
...
   at MongoDB.Driver.MongoCollectionImpl`1.Watch[TResult](PipelineDefinition`2 pipeline, ChangeStreamOptions options, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at CosmosChangeStream.Program.Main(String[] args) in Program.cs:line
```

I have also tried

```
cursor = collection.Watch();
```

This line is written like this in many getting started articles, but it throws another exception.

```
MongoDB.Driver.MongoCommandException: Command aggregate failed: fullDocument option must be "updateLookup"..
```

Obviously it is looking for projection. Wondering how so many examples have code that does not run. But this not my problem, my problem is to get an IEnumerable Change Stream for all inserts to one or all collections in a database, and be on my way.
I have validated my connection to the database and collection by reading a document.

Thanks to any one who looks at this

Comment: Did you try to add the projection stage as the error asks?

Comment: projection is a pipeline stage. There is no projection neither in pipeline nor in options in the code snippet you posted.

Comment: Thank you. If you add a line with a changestream document projection to the pipeline that selects all fields , I will accept the answer

Comment: I am glad if my comments helped. I would answer straight away if I was familiar with c# syntax. Unfortunately I can merely read it, but am happy with you to provide full-scale answer to help others who may face the same issue in the future.

Comment: Sure, trying to get the projection definition right. 
var ChangeStreamProjection = Builders<ChangeStreamDocument<BsonDocument>>.Projection.Exclude("Tags");
var pipeline = new EmptyPipelineDefinition<ChangeStreamDocument<BsonDocument>>()
                   .Match("{ operationType: 'insert' }")
                   .Project(ChangeStreamProjection);
Still the same exception. Will definitely post as soon as I can get it right

Comment: Take a look at the docs https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/mongodb/change-streams?tabs=csharp

Answer (score 0):

I was able to make it work with the help of this article:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/mongodb/change-streams?tabs=csharp
This has the pipeline definition including match and projection staging.